# How to check if matlab toolbox installed in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am working on Matlab R2011a student edition. I want to run some demos provided in Matlab which require some toolbox like Embedded Coder and EDA Simulator Link.

I want to check if those toolboxes are installed in my current version of matlab and if yes how can I check if the  licenses are valid.

The reference to this link didn't help me:
[How would one check for installed MATLAB toolboxes in a script/function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060382/how-would-one-check-for-installed-matlab-toolboxes-in-a-script-function)  because I need at least the short name of those toolboxes like "control" states for "Control System Toolbox" by using the command *ver control*.

Any suggestion...

Answer (score 12):

To check that the toolbox is installed, use

```
v = ver;
any(strcmp(toolboxName, {v.Name}))
```

where `toolboxName` is the name of the toolbox you want to check.

To check that the licence is valid, use

```
license('test', toolboxName)
```

Comment: I knew that. But the problem by finding the specific name for the toolbox to enter it as argument.

Comment: WARNING: the toolbox name is not guaranteed to be the same for ver and license! For example the optimization toolbox is 'optim' in ver/verLessThan but 'optimization_toolbox' in license. The name used by ver appears to be just the name of directory that contains the toolbox under <matlabroot>/toolbox/. <sigh>

Answer (score 4):

easily use **ver** command. it will list all installed toolboxes and their versions. the other way is to check from the **start** button.

Also you can use the [existing function in FileExchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/51794-istoolboxavailable) called `isToolboxAvailable`. The usage is as follows:

```
result = isToolboxAvailable('image processing toolbox','error');
```

Answer (score 3):

you can always check out the main help documentation which generally lists the toolbox.
Or if you press "Start" (the Matlab start, not Windows) the list of installed toolboxes will be organised by category

Answer (score 3):

Here is a dirty solution:

```
try
    <funktion from specific toolbox>
    <do this if it is available>
catch
    <do this if it is not
end
```

Comment: Simple and just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

The names of the toolboxes that are returned by the `license` function are the same as what is in the license file.  The license file will either be on the local PC or on a FLEXlm license server, depending on your environment.  On Windows, check in `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011a\licenses` for a license file, which is typically named something like `license.lic` or `network.lic`.  Open the file in your favorite editor (notepad will do).  If you see text that says `SERVER` followed by a hostname, MAC address, and port number, then you're using a network license and you'll have to ask your systems administrator.  Otherwise, there should be an `INCREMENT` line for each licensed product and the name of the product as used by the `license` function is given following the `INCREMENT` keyword.  If you're on a UNIX or Linux system, you may have to dig around a bit to find the path for the license file (or perhaps someone else can provide this?).

Edit: My MATLAB install is in a non-standard path.  Changed instructions to give the default path.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case somebody stumbles upon this in 2022. There are now several built-in [add-on utilities](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/add-ons.html#:%7E:text=Add-On%20Explorer.-,Functions,-expand%20all) to check if add-ons are installed. Notably:

- [matlab.addons.installedAddons](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.addons.installedaddons.html): Will list all installed add-ons with (long) Name, Version, Identifier (aka short name/hash)
- [matlab.addons.isAddonEnabled](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.addons.isaddonenabled.html): To check if a given add-on is enabled

Comment: Did indeed stumble upon this in 2022 (well, 2023, technically). Thanks!