# matlab parfor seems to have no effect?

Tags: matlab, parfor

Based on the following code and running results, it seems parfor does not parallel the execution at all. Is this because there are some secret settings in matlab to enable this parfor feature?

```
>> tic;
for i = 1 : 4
pause(3);
end
toc;
Elapsed time is 12.039229 seconds.
>>  tic;
parfor i = 1 : 4
pause(3);
end
toc;
Elapsed time is 12.046663 seconds.
```

Comment: Do you have the Parallel Computing toolbox and have you configured it?

Comment: You may not see the benefit of parallelising with just 4 items - when I tried it the parfor version took `Elapsed time is 13.146371 seconds`.  (But with `i = 1 : 10` it took closer to 6 seconds)  That'll just be down to the overhead of starting the parallel pool etc.

Comment: Hi Rollen, thanks for your suggestion! I am also suspecting that. Do you have any ideas on how to check if I have the parallel computing toolbox installed and how to configure it?

Comment: Hi Partha, thanks for your suggestions! I have tried to use `i = 1 : 10` but it takes about 30 seconds...
    `tic;
    parfor i = 1 : 10
    pause(3);
    end
    toc;
    Elapsed time is 30.093446 seconds.`

Comment: I ran your exact code on a computer with 4 cores and got about a 4x speed up (`3.111722 seconds`). You can check if the `Parallel Computing Toolbox` is installed using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926021/how-to-check-if-matlab-toolbox-installed-in-matlab) technique.

Comment: @Jiong YANG After running your code type `license inuse` to see which toolboxes you are using.

Comment: I see, I don't have the parallel computing toolbox license installed on my computer... Btw, here is the syntax to check if the parallel computing toolbox is installed based on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926021/how-to-check-if-matlab-toolbox-installed-in-matlab): `license('test', 'Parallel Computing Toolbox')`. Thanks very much, @Rollen @Partha @eigenchris @matlabgui, for all your suggestions in helping to identity the issue!