# How to check MATLAB Coder version in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

How do I check whether the MATLAB Coder package is available in my MATLAB installation?

Comment: It seems that there is pretty nice explanation about MATLAB `ver` and `license` commands [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060382/how-would-one-check-for-installed-matlab-toolboxes-in-a-script-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call 'ver' in your code. Then if you parse the output, you can see weather MATLAB Coder is installed or not:

```
>> v = ver;
>> setdiff({v.Name}, 'MATLAB')'

ans = 

    'Aerospace Blockset'
    'Aerospace Toolbox'
    'Bioinformatics Toolbox'
    'Communications System Toolbox'
    'Computer Vision System Toolbox'
    'Control System Toolbox'
    'Conversion to SeDuMi'
    'Curve Fitting Toolbox'
    'DSP System Toolbox'
    'Database Toolbox'
    'Datafeed Toolbox'
    'Econometrics Toolbox'
    'Embedded Coder'
    'Financial Derivatives Toolbox'
    'Financial Toolbox'
    'Fixed-Income Toolbox'
    'Fixed-Point Toolbox'
    'Fuzzy Logic Toolbox'
    'Global Optimization Toolbox'
    'Image Acquisition Toolbox'
    'Image Processing Toolbox'
    'Instrument Control Toolbox'
    'MATLAB Coder'
    'MATLAB Distributed Computing Server'
    'MATLAB Report Generator'
    'Mapping Toolbox'
    'Model Predictive Control Toolbox'
    'Neural Network Toolbox'
    'Optimization Toolbox'
    'Parallel Computing Toolbox'
    'Partial Differential Equation Toolbox'
    'Phased Array System Toolbox'
    'RF Toolbox'
    'Robust Control Toolbox'
    'Signal Processing Toolbox'
    'SimBiology'
    'SimDriveline'
    'SimElectronics'
    'SimEvents'
    'SimHydraulics'
    'SimMechanics'
    'SimPowerSystems'
    'SimRF'
    'Simscape'
    'Simulink'
    'Simulink 3D Animation'
    'Simulink Coder'
    'Simulink Control Design'
    'Simulink Design Optimization'
    'Simulink Fixed Point'
    'Simulink Report Generator'
    'Simulink Verification and Validation'
    'Stateflow'
    'Statistical Graphics Toolbox'
    'Statistical Parametric Mapping'
    'Statistics Toolbox'
    'Symbolic Math Toolbox'
    'System Identification Toolbox'
    'SystemTest'
    'Wavelet Toolbox'
```