# What does the following message mean? Does it mean that no parallel for toolbox?

Tags: matlab, parfor

When I run my program, I get the following error message:

> Diagnostic Information:
>   Feature: Distrib_Computing_Toolbox 
>   License path: C:\Users\chleung\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2017a_licenses;\sepcnet\shares\MatlabW64\licenses\license.dat;\sepcnet\shares\MatlabW64\licenses\network.lic 
>   Licensing error: -5,0.
>   Error using distcompserialize64
>
> Unable to checkout a license for the Parallel Computing Toolbox.
>
> Error in parallel.internal.pool.serialize (line 21)
>       ser = distcompserialize64( data );
>
> Error in remoteParallelFunction (line 62)
>       out = parallel.internal.pool.serialize(errToSerialize);

Does it mean no licenses for parallel computing in my computer?

Comment: Well, at least it could not find it. Do you have the license?

Comment: Related question: [How would one check for installed MATLAB toolboxes in a script/function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2060382/52738)

Answer (score 0):

It means that it can't find a license. The most likely cause is that you don't have one - however, it's possible that there's some other reason, such as:

- you have a license, but it's stored in a path that isn't being checked
- you are using a network license, and there is a problem checking the license server